# Sending strings via ajax to Node.js server running express.js don't work properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, get-request

I'm trying to send strings from my site to my Node.js server, but when they are received, for some reasons some characters are lost.

```
// Client:
microAjax("/foo?test="+encodeURI("this is ++ a test"), function callback(){});

// Server:
app.get('/foo',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.param("test"));
});
```

Here, both "+" characters appear missing on the server.

Answer (score 2):

try `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`. That will give you `%2B` for the plus signs which should work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

> Note that encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded, which are treated as special characters in GET and POST requests. encodeURIComponent, however, does encode these characters. These behaviors are most likely not consistent across browsers.